# Reply Tweet Automatically Using Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

my goal is to reply to a certain tweet using tweepy with some pause (time.sleep())
the reply format is *status* and the value of i at the end. but my code isn't working and i don't know why. (nb: it only replies once and doesn't print the report)

```
import tweepy
import random
import datetime
import time


def spam():
    for i in range(amount):
        send = str(status) + " " + str(i+1)
        pause = random.randint(5,12)

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("xxxx", "xxxx")
        auth.set_access_token("xxxx-xxxx", "xxxx")
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        api.update_status(send, in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid , auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
        print("succes, pause =",pause+"s\t",datetime.datetime.now()) # for report
        time.sleep(pause)

amount = int(input("amount>> "))
status = input("status>> ")
tweetid = input("id>> ")

spam()
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: @Harmon758 no, but it didn't work as planned. It only replied once

Comment: What are your inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Twitter blocks tweets that are similar to one another. Only one such tweet can go out. Even I'd tried varying the time between tweets and also tried to change a character or two, bit still it got blocked. Nothing wrong with your code, it's Twitter's Defence Mechanism that has kicked in to prevent spam. Also be careful, your API access might also get blocked if you try to spam.

Also you don't need to authenticate every time you run through the loop, you can do it only once and get the `api` object and you can use it in the loop as below

```
import tweepy
import random
import datetime
import time


def spam():
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("xxxx", "xxxx")
  auth.set_access_token("xxxx-xxxx", "xxxx")
  api = tweepy.API(auth)
  for i in range(amount):
    send = str(status) + " " + str(i+1)
    pause = random.randint(5,12)
    api.update_status(send, in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid , auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
    print("succes, pause =",pause+"s\t",datetime.datetime.now()) # for report
    time.sleep(pause)

amount = int(input("amount>> "))
status = input("status>> ")
tweetid = input("id>> ")

spam()
```

Comment: I have run the code before but not using Time and Datetime and it worked. But when I combine it with both Time and Datetime, it didn't work.